# Read and export excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, exceljs

**I want to create a single web page using html and javascript in which user can upload an excel(.xlsx, .xls) file as an input.**

1. After uploading excel sheet the web page should use the javascript logic.
2. It could read that excel sheet and make changes using some js logic.
3. After writing into excel, web page should have a download button to download the new excel sheet.

Do I need to use Node js to do that or is it possible to use some cdn script tags of excel-js library, which is not working for me(I dont know why)

> ```
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exceljs/4.2.1/exceljs.min.js" integrity="sha512-DPjFYmSXYGB7/5k/Z4h5iw1i29Vl//jj3I7v79DRy+T0o4KssDku6Hf7ImlIV87KmNIh+euT5H0LJhQmTnbC/A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> ```

Whenever I try to use some function of this library like , it throws me error

```
function excelChange (event) {
var input = event.target.files[0]
const workbook = createAndFillWorkbook();
const sheet = workbook.xlsx.writeFile(input);
console.log(sheet)}
```

**What should be my approach to achieve this goal ?**

Answer (score 0):

CSV Excel files are comma separated like this
name, age,
john, 33,
bob, 55,

So you could just read it as a string and make an array from it. Then render the array into a table. Do the reverse to make a CSV Excel file.

```js
const excelString = `
    name, age,
    john, 33,
    bob, 55,
`;

function parse(string){
  return string.trim().split("\n").map(row => row.trim().split(",").map(val => val.trim()).filter(str => str));
}

const parsed = parse(excelString);
const [head, ...body] = parsed;

function addElement(tag, data, editable){
  const elm = document.createElement(tag);
  if(data) elm.textContent = data;
  if(editable) elm.contentEditable = true;
  return elm;
}

document.querySelector("table").appendChild(
    addElement("tr")
);

head.map(header => {
    document.querySelector("tr:last-child").appendChild(
        addElement("th", header, true)
    );
});


body.map(row => {
    document.querySelector("table").appendChild(addElement("tr"));
    row.map(item => {
        document.querySelector("tr:last-child").appendChild(
            addElement("td", item, true)
        );
    });
});

function table2excel(){
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).map(row => {
        return Array.from(row.querySelectorAll("th, td"))
                    .map(elm => elm.textContent);
    }).map(row => row.join(",")).join(",\n").concat(",")
}

const newExcel = table2excel();

console.log(newExcel)

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => console.log(table2excel()))
```

```html
<table />
<button>Log table</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but how could I read an excel file and write changes ?

Comment: Found this guide on converting excel and csv files to json. I'm guessing the library they are using also can write them afterwards.
https://blog.bitsrc.io/csv-excel-to-json-in-javascript-70e61a1dc32d